# Replacing a Hard Disk with a clone fails

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sles

I just cloned a disk (A) using dd into the same kind of disk (B):

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

Now, I want to boot the server with new disk (B) instead of old (A). But i getting an error  during start:

```
............................Could not find /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c5004c05c167-part3.
Want me to fall back to /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c5004c05c167-part3? (Y/n) 
y
Waiting for device /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c5004c05c167-part3 to appear:             
..............................not found -- exiting to /bin/sh
```

I think the problem is that it query the disk using old disk (A) ID (scsi-35000c5004c05c167). Where can i change it to use new disk (B) ID?

I'm using Suse Linux Enterprise 11

More info:

```
$ ls /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*           
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c5004bab5733
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c5004bab5733-part1
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c5004bab5733-part2
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c5004bab5733-part3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your paths in:

- /etc/fstab
- /boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: after exiting to /bin/sh there is no /etc/fstab not /boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: Boot using a live CD or temporarily change the boot info as BMDan suggests, then make the change.

Comment: @Zhen, you almost certainly are going to need to boot the system with a livecd.

Comment: i was able to change '/etc/fstab' but there is no '/boot/grub/menu.lst' file

Comment: @mikeyB what do you change in that line and replace it with what?

Answer (score 2):

you need to find and replace that uuid in your grub configuration, something like /boot/grub/menu.lst  in grub.

in grub 2, /boot/grub/grub.cfg is generated when you run update-grub, so you could temporarily modify that file and boot, and then change the grub settings and run update-grub once you have booted into your OS.

another option is to temporarily replace the uuid reference to the actual disk partition, and again fix that later.

Comment: just to nitpick a little, but what he displayed isn't a UUID.  UUIDs are globally unique and follow a certain format.  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Answer (score 2):

In grub's configuration, you'll have a line that reads something like:

```
kernel /foo root=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c5004c05c167-part3
```

You'll need to change that line.  You may also have, as @MikeyB points out, similar entries in /etc/fstab; you'll need to change those, as well.

Alternately, to boot off of the cloned disk, you can do a one-time edit of grub's configuration by hitting any key to enter menu mode, then "e" to edit the startup entry in question, then "e" again to edit the line.  Make the changes, then hit enter to "save" (I use the term loosely) the modified line, and press "b" to boot the active entry.  Don't forget to then make your changes permanent through the same steps as above!